# recover corrupted documents from backup

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library

HI I have some documents and image files that were corrupted and we have the backup of the same content database and how to copy or relapse these corrupted documents.

I restored the backup to test server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover items from an unattached content database by following the instructions in the article at [https://technet.microsoft.com/](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269602(v=office.14).aspx) - you can use either the GUI or PowerShell to perform the actions.

Essentially this attaches the database to the central administration web application and allows you to export content (e.g. a list or library), which can then be imported to a suitable location in one of the main content web applications. Note that unless you want to replace the contents of the library that contains corruption, you should restore this content to a temporary location, which then allows you to grab copies of the items that you need.

The steps consist of:

1. Open the unattached database
2. Navigate through the content contained in the database to locate the content that is required
3. Export the required content, this produces an export file containing the content in the usual way
4. Use PowerShell to import this content to a temporary location (or the original location if you want to overwrite the content) using the Import-SPWeb command (yes, this also works for lists and libraries - see [Import-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.14).aspx) for details)

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated process in SharePoint for item level recovery. You have a couple of options.

1. if versioning is enabled then restore the document from the previous version.
2. The second option restores the backup in another farm and then manually copy the documents from that farm to production farm. ( using the open with explorer options[both library from production and test] move the file from test to prod.